# PHP ODBC parameterized query ERROR Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

im trying to use parameterized query in PHP using ODBC, but im got this error message

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters'., SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter in C:\xamppold\htdocs\poling\validate.php on line 99

Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters'., SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter in C:\xamppold\htdocs\poling\validate.php on line 100
```

Im using this code:

```
$stmt1    = odbc_prepare($koneksi, 'INSERT INTO tb_pemilu (id_calon,id_status,nim_mhs,ip) values (?,?,?,?)');
                    $stmt2    = odbc_prepare($koneksi, 'INSERT INTO tb_pemilu (id_calon,id_status,nim_mhs,ip) values (?,?,?,?)');



                    $values1 = array($id_cln_senat, $id_sts_senat, $nima,$ipaddr);
                    $values2 = array($id_cln_balma, $id_sts_balma, $nima,$ipaddr);

                    $exec0 = odbc_execute($stmt1, $values1);
                    $exec1 = odbc_execute($stmt2, $values2);
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters` works since SQL Server 2012

Comment: hummm, thanks, im using sql server 2008 r2, so is there anyway to use parameterized query with sql server 2008 r2 ? @gofr1

Comment: It is strange, that this proc is called, if you are using 2008 r2. Maybe some connectivity/driver problem.

Comment: im using standar connection using odbc_connect, like this
$koneksi = odbc_connect($server,$username,$pass); @gofr1

Comment: Have you tried to `open` then `prepare` and `execute` first statement, then do the same with second statement?

Comment: ya but just odbc_connect and odbc_close,  im use this example for my code 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php @gofr1

Comment: My guess is that ODBC Driver somehow is trying to run `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters` with the query. But failed to find it, because SQL Server 2008 r2 does not have this SP.

Comment: yup, i think on sql server 2008 doesn't suport sp_describe_undeclared_parameters, cause when i type it on SQL Server management studio, it say Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters', i'll try to use sql server 2012, thanks for your help bro @gofr1